# Dynamically binding a datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I'm binding data to a datagrid dynamically but it does not shows the data. It gives me this five columns in it: RowError, RowState, table, ItemArray and HasError.

But the row count is correct it gives same row count as I have in database.

This is the Vb code:

```
Dim con As New OdbcConnection("dsn=PAUSPAN")
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("select * from tbl_chart", con)

Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
'Dim dt As New DataTable("a")
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds.Tables.Add("a")

da.Fill(ds, "a")
MsgBox(ds.Tables("a").Rows.Count.ToString)

DataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("a").AsEnumerable.ToList()
'DataGrid1.DataContext = ds.DefaultViewManager

con.Close()
```

And this is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="datagrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"        
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="datagrid" Height="344" Width="599">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="486,225,0,0" Name="Button1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <DataGrid Height="241" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="12,12,0,0" 
                  Name="DataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="386" ItemsSource="{Binding ds}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

how to solve this problem? how do it bind the dataset to datagrid dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Bind `ItemsSource` with `DataView` instead of `DataTable`. You can get DataView with either of the approaches mentioned below -

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("a").DefaultView;
```

OR use extension method `AsDataView` -

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("a").AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit mixing dynamic and static binding. you should remove `ItemsSource="{Binding ds}"` from XAML and  `DataGrid1.DataContext = ds.DefaultViewManager` from code behind as  you're communicating with ItemsSource from code behind.